# How to list open source license owner

Tags: licensing, open-source

I am releasing software developed in a university under the Apache 2.0 license.  I would like advice on who to list as the license owner.  Would I list only my boss who co-authored the software and maintains the code base, or both my boss and the institution, or just the institution?

I'm inclined to put my bosses name and institution, but I wanted to find out of that was an acceptable practice.

Also do you know if multiple individuals are ever listed as license owners?

Answer (score 2):

The usual situations are

- The copyright holders are one or more individuals. This is often the case with small to medium sized projects that got started as a personal project, or
- The copyright holder is a legal entity such as a company, institution or foundation. This is usually the case with large open source projects and projects started by an organization.

This means that it is very unusual to list both an organization (like your institution) *and* some individuals as copyright holders, especially if those individuals are also employed by the organization.

To get a definitive answer on who is the copyright holder, you must ask your boss or the administrators of your university. Most likely, the copyright lies with the university.